# When is the short story "Fugitive" set in chronological order?

Tags: short-stories, timeline, jim-butcher, the-dresden-files

I'm talking about "The Dresden Files" book series. Specifically, the short story is set inside "Instinct: An Animal Rescuers Anthoogy".